# Get trap sender's IP with PySNMP

Tags: pysnmp

I build a small SNMP v3 trap receiver in python with pysnmp. In our network, the snmp enigine id and the users/passwords are equal on different machines. So i need the snmp trap senders ip address to identify the sending machine. 
How can i get the address, is there any function/method in pysnmp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is generally discouraged in SNMP to rely on peer address because of potential proxy/NAT/etc in-between. That probably explains why peer address information is not exposed in abstract SNMP APIs.

Do get hold of peer address in pysnmp you could use the `observer` feature:

```
# Callback function for receiving notifications
def cbFun(snmpEngine, stateReference, contextEngineId, contextName,
          varBinds, cbCtx):
    execContext = snmpEngine.observer.getExecutionContext(
        'rfc3412.receiveMessage:request'
    )

    print('Notification from %s:%s' % execContext['transportAddress'])
```

Here is the [complete example](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v3arch/asyncore/manager/ntfrcv/transport-tweaks.html#receive-notifications-noting-peer-address).